# How to use jQuery to select the first image in a new window

Tags: jquery

I have code like this below which uses a web service and opens a window with an image if one exists, otherwise there will be nothing in the the new window. I want to use jQuery to select the first image tag in the new window so that if there is no image tag I can instead display **"No Image Found"** in the new window.

```
function showImagePopup(transactionID) {
    try {
        var sFeatures = 'status=no,width=' + 500 + ',height=' + 380;
        var url = "/JSON/GetTransactionImage?transactionID=" + transactionID;
        var imageWindow = window.open (url,"_blank",sFeatures);     
        imageWindow.focus();
    } catch (err) {
        // using alert for debugging purposes,
        // but probably want to catch and ignore any errors
        alert(err);  
    }       
}
```

I am not sure how to reference something with jquery that I presume is outside the dom. I know how to use jquery to select objects in the current dom.

Comment: Off-topic, but catching and ignoring all errors is not a good idea.

Comment: Have you tried anything to solve the problem?

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to try to solve the problem.... To solve your problem (like you said), look in your DOM for the image tag, check the jQuery object returned and then, open a new window based on the result...

Comment: I tried using $(imageWindow).find("img") but it returns an empty object in Firebug whether there is an image or not. My problem may be that imageWindow is not a jquery object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery `find()` function to check for the presence of an image tag.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ewjBp/44/)

Comment: Would I use something like $(imageWindow).find("img")?

Comment: Note that `find()` never returns `undefined` itself. It returns an empty jQuery object if no element matches the selector, and applying `val()` to that object will, in turn, produce `undefined`. Testing for empty jQuery objects can be achieved through their `length` property.

Comment: Yes, i agree with Frédéric Hamidi. 
Seth F - i have updated the demo to help you exactly with the image tag.

Comment: This doesn't address my problem with the image in a new window. I know how to use jquery to select objects, but if it is in a new window isn't it outside the dom? I have several img tags in my main page so just selecting for img in the current page will always get results.

Comment: Are you using JSPs in your application?